# php curl upload percent

Tags: php, curl

I can upload files to different server with this code:

```
updateproduct($product['id'], 'uploading');
$data['video_file'] = "@".$filepath;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json['upload_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1550);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I want to update database every percent. updateproduct function updates database. How can I get current upload percent?

Answer (score 0):

Use the curl callback to progress meter function: [CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html)